# Parameters not passing correctly between classes

Tags: react-native

I have a flat list, and made a separate class for the flat list element. In the place I am displaying the flatlist, I do it like so:

```
return (
             <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.globalPostsArray}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.key}
                />
              </View>   
        )
```

This works fine. The function I wrote to render the elements of the flatlist, `renderItem`, looks like this:

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <FeedCellClass 
        username={item.username} 
        description={item.description} 
    />
);
```

And the `feedCellClass` looks like this:

```
class FeedCellClass extends React.Component{ 

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        username: this.props.params.username,
        description: this.props.params.description

    }
}

....rest of the class
```

For some reason, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.params.username')
```

Which makes me think I am passing the parameters incorrectly. How can I solve this issue? I found a few resources online which I followed and have reached this point, but the parameters are not being passed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing props correctly

```
<FeedCellClass 
    username={item.username} 
    description={item.description} 
/>
```

You are passing two props username and description and both are strings, and you can access it like below.

```
 this.state = {
        username: this.props.username,
        description: this.props.description
    }
```

As there is no prop called params when you try to access the username property of the undefined prop which is param its throwing this error.

If you pass like below

```
<FeedCellClass params={{username:"123",description:"456"}}/>
```

Then you can access like above